# Good reason to convert LONGTEXT column to smaller width if field is smaller?

Tags: mysql, performance, schema

We have a database that uses a LONGTEXT type for a column that does not need that much space. The maximum row size currently has about 6500 characters and that's with a few million inserts so it's very unlikely we will ever need more space.  Is it worthwhile to try to reduce the allocated size of this column?  Will we see performance improvements?

We are using MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on a lot of aspects. What is the character set of that column? What row format are you using? (You can check row format with: `show table status like 'table_name'`)

Answer (score 3):

Let's do the math.

- 6500 characters, even in `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` takes no more than 26000 bytes.
- `TEXT` has a limit of 64K bytes and needs a hidden 2-byte length field.
- `LONGTEXT` has a 4-byte length field.
- Let's say (for the 'math') that the average row length, including this text, is 3000 bytes.

Math...

- Savings of switching from `LONGTEXT` to `TEXT`: 2 bytes per row
- Percentage space savings:  2/3000 = 0.06%
- Performance improvement:  Less than that.

Conclusion...  We have spent much more effort than this minuscule improvement is worth.  (But you probably learned some details.)

Comment: afair length is 2 bytes even for LONGTEXT. It's a length of a chunk in a page which is < 16k. so no reason to switch to TEXT at all.

Comment: @akuzminsky - Yes, it is chunked, but I think the total length is stored in the record.

Comment: Can you show where ?

Comment: @akuzminsky - A guess:  In the 20-byte structure that lives in the record to point to the chain of off-record chunks for big `TEXTs`/`BLOBs`.  On the other hand, watching `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` makes me wonder if `LENGTH()` does read the chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it will be worthwhile to change the type.  You may save a byte or two for the length field of each column value if using TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT,  but that will be insignificant compared to the size of your data.

VARCHAR and TEXT columns are handled the same way in InnoDB, so there is no reason to switch to VARCHAR either.